# Find expected number of draws from first principles

Tags: probability

This is a variation of a common probability problem: Given a bag of N blue marbles and M red marbles what's the number of expected draws until you get a blue marble?

With $p_R = \frac{M}{M+N}$ and $p_B = \frac{N}{M+N}$, the expected number of trials before the first success is a discrete RV distributed according to a Geometric distribution. This distribution's expected value is known and in this case is $\mathbb{E}[X]= \frac{1}{p_{B}}=\frac{M+N}{N}$.

Given that this is correct (which I think it is), is there a way to derive this result from first principles, e.g. if we didn't know about the Geometric distribution?

Comment: Drawing with replacement or without replacement?

Comment: Good question, the problem statement did not specify. Let's take without replacement.

Comment: Then you do not have a geometric distribution.  With replacement is easier as $E[X]=1+\frac{M}{M+N}E[X]$

Comment: You're right. I guess a first principles answer would cover both cases (?) I can edit the question to clarify things.

Comment: Without replacement, it will look like this $E(X) = 1 + \frac{M}{N + M} (1 + \frac{M-1}{N+ M -1}(1 + \frac{M-2}{N+ M -2}(...+ \frac{M-K}{N+ M - K}(1 + ...)... + ...)$

Comment: In both with and without replacement shouldn't 1 be weighted by $p_B = \frac{N}{M+N}$?

Comment: @AutomEng The first $1$ is for the first draw, which always happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say $D(N,M)$ is the expected number of draws until the first blue when starting from $N$ blue marbles and $M$ red marbles.  You start by drawing one marble and if it is blue you stop, while if you draw a red marble, with probability $\frac{M}{N+M}$ you draw again.

**With replacement** this means $D(N,M) = 1+ \frac{M}{N+M} D(N,M)$ which is easily solved to give (as you say) $$D(N,M) = \frac{N+M}{N}$$

**Without replacement** this means $D(N,M) = 1+ \frac{M}{N+M} D(N,M-1)$ starting with  $D(N,0)=1$ as you must draw blue if there is no red.  So $D(N,1)=1+\frac{1}{N+1}\times 1=\frac{N+2}{N+1}$ and then $D(N,2)=1+\frac{2}{N+2}\times \frac{N+2}{N+1} = \frac{N+3}{N+1}$ and so on.  It is an easy induction to show $$D(N,M) = \frac{N+M+1}{N+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the number of trials until the first success, with each trial having success probability $p$. Then
$$E(X)=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}P(X\geq r)=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{r-1}=\frac{1}{1-(1-p)}.$$

Comment: That is the geometric distribution (with replacement) using a geometric series.  I am not sure that is what is wanted here

Comment: @Henry Why not? The question explicitly says it is asking about a geometric distribution.